# How to do basic animation with GTK3,C and Cairo only

Tags: c, opengl, animation, gtk3, cairo

Let assume i have a GTK window with a drawing area and a button in it.

1. When the application is run it will show ball.
2. When the button is pressed it will start bouncing from one side to other.
3. When the button is pressed again it stop bouncing.

Also the window shows the current XY co-ordinates of the ball in the bottom left corner (inside the drawing area).

I want to use **C**, **GTK3** and **CAIRO** only.

I have Googled and found an animation example not with GTk3 but GTK's previous versions instead. Those don't work with GTK3. I have also read CAIRO's official, zetecode's tutorials and some other sites. Nowhere did I find any solution to my problem.

I know how to do so with OpenGL and it's very easy, but I cannot apply the same logic with CAIRO and GTK3.  Please do not suggest to use GtkGlExt.  I **don't** want to use it.

Comment: don't write your title IN ALL CAPS

Comment: So what did you try so far (beyond reading), show some code.

Answer (score -1):

A note here (even though you haven't show some code): 
For all these years cairo developer has worked hard to induce compatibility into their code. As I quote from cairo-doc : "Moving from a release to any later version (release, snapshot, development) is always guaranteed to provide compatibility.".

So far (all i know), cairo only has 6 major releases. 
Interaction with cairo in gtk is done by Gdk, and by the sound of what you are trying to do, the code (googled) i guess it will only contains GtkDrawingArea, cairo_t, cairo_arc, cairo_move_to, GtkButton (with 2 GCallbacks), some gdk-cairo interaction functions, gtk_widget_translate_coordinates (), GRand / random(), and loop. 
Those items has been there from Gtk+2.0 and still exists now.
If the code doesn't work try to delete the "coordinate widget" part (it probably using a custom GtkWidget). Try to put coordinate outside GtkDrawingArea (i.e GtkWindow);